# MLE : Getting wrong answer

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I am trying to solve the critical point for an MLE but my answer is wrong

PDF is as follows : $\frac{x}{\theta^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta^2}}$ 1 - >( X>=0) , theta > 0 ( 1 is the indicator variable)

Critical point at l(theta), I have calculated the MLE by doing the product of the pdf, which gives something like n * log(x) - n*log(theta^2) - Sum X^2 / 2* theta^2
I then differentiate this function with respect to theta, i get sqrt(2*Xnbar^2)
but this is wrong. Can you please help me where I am doing the mistake? May be i am missing something when applying log and n for the product.

thank you

Comment: It's difficult to check because your notation is ambiguous--please consider marking it up using MathJax.  It does appear that your differentiation is incorrect: what happened to the term that is produced when differentiating $n\log(\theta^2)$ with respect to $\theta$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am not very well versed with MathJax :( . For yor question i would say its (2*n/theta)

Comment: `$\theta$` = $\theta$  `$\frac{x}{\theta^2}$` = $\frac{x}{\theta^2}$

Comment: Basically, enclose MathJax script in $ ... $. You usually use the \ character to activate special characters, or the fraction script, or whatever. Basic tutorial here. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Wrote the PDF in Mathjax

Answer (score 1):

The log of the likelihood should be

$$-\frac{\sum _i^n x_i^2}{2 \theta ^2}+\sum _i^n \log (x_i)-2 n \log (\theta )$$

And differentiating this with respect to $\theta$ finds

$$\frac{\sum _i^n x_i^2}{\theta ^3}-\frac{2 n}{\theta }$$

Setting that to zero results in the maximum likelihood estimator

$$\hat{\theta}=\frac{\sqrt{\sum _i^n x_i^2}}{\sqrt{2n}}$$